# Why isn't $(this).val() working in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The 3rd line of the following code

```
var chrtli = chi.find('li:not(.blank-space)'); // Get list element that holds chart
chrtli.attr('value',ciarr[k].val); // Set value attribute to the list element
chrtli.text($(this).val()); // Add inner text to the list element equal to its value
```

isn't doing anything, although the console also isn't printing out any errors. What I'm trying to do is make the 3rd line a more scalable version of

```
chrtli.text(ciarr[k].val);
```

so that I don't have to use `ciarr[k].val` twice in the span of 2 lines and so I can refer to a reference rather than a value.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Show the entire code. List element does not support `value` attribute.

Comment: We need to know what `chi` is searching through, and what `this` is.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the function you're calling?

Comment: Scanning the DOM to get the same value that you'd already had in hand is not very scalable! I'd rather do `var someVal = ciarr[k].val;` and use it where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
var chrtli = chi.find('li:not(.blank-space)'); // Get list element that holds chart
var val = ciarr[k].val;
chrtli.attr('value',val); // Set value attribute to the list element
chrtli.text(val); // Add inner text to the list element equal to its value
```

Is this what you were looking for? "this" actually refers to where your function is binded to (either window or an element)

Comment: Bad question on my part, but this is probably the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` returns the value of a form element.
`<li>`s do not have a value.

You want `.text()`.